# Which templating engine is this?

Tags: java, .net, templates, template-engine

At my current place of work we have to use a web-service which works with a text template we feed to it. Now we would like to use those templates at other places in code and so I wondered what template language that could possibly be and if it's some off-the-shelf or off-the-net software. It's presumably something from Java or .NET world, but can be essentially anything.

It's got the following tokens:

- `$$variable$$`
- `@@function@@`
- `@@function_call[$$parameter$$]@@`
- Condition: `@@IF[$$boolen$$]@@THEN@@Text@@[ELSE@@Text@@]ENDIF@@`

Does someone recognize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@@Looks like a really grim one@@, $$made$$ by someone with @@@no sense@@@ of making things loook **attractive** $when$ written:@@@@@@$$$$[][]

I would be surprised if it was the syntax of an actual product or open-source template engine.

Answer (score 2):

it seems an home-grown templating system. At least it is not:

- Velocity (Java)
- StringTemplate (Java)
- FreeMarker (Java)